# How do I convert this SQL query into a Grails or GORM query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I write the below SQL query in Grails or GORM?

```
select email, count(*) as c FROM orders GROUP BY email
```

Comment: Which version of GORM?

Comment: grails version 2.2.4

Answer (score 4):

Use [Projections](http://grails.asia/grails-criteria-projections-examples)!

```
def result = Orders.createCriteria().list() {
  projections {
    groupProperty("email")
    count()
  }
  order("email", "asc")
}
```

Edit: Or HQL, I guess...

```
def list = Orders.executeQuery("select email, count(*) from Orders group by email")
list.each { item ->
    def email = item[0]
    def count = item[1]
    println "There are ${count} people with the e-mail address of ${email}"
}
```

(I just eyeballed that, but I think it's about right, might take some tweaking)

Comment: Strongly recommend projections over raw SQL or HQL when possible.  Much easier to maintain and refactor as necessary.